# fork and join using Akka

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future, akka, actor

problem statement: I have a portfolio of securities that need to be processed in a parallel fashion. In Java i used a threadpool to process each security, and use a latch to countdown. Once complete I do some merging etc.

So I message my SecurityProcessor(which is an actor), and wait on all the futures to complete. In the end I use a MergeHelper to do the post-processing. The SecurityProcessor takes a security, does some i/o and processing and replies a Security

```
  val listOfFutures = new ListBuffer[Future[Security]]()
  var portfolioResponse: Portfolio = _
  for (security <- portfolio.getSecurities.toList) {
    val securityProcessor = actorOf[SecurityProcessor].start()
    listOfFutures += (securityProcessor ? security) map {
      _.asInstanceOf[Security]
    }
  }
  val futures = Future.sequence(listOfFutures.toList)
  futures.map {
    listOfSecurities =>
      portfolioResponse = MergeHelper.merge(portfolio, listOfSecurities)
  }.get
```

Is this design correct, and is there a better/cooler way to implement this common problem using akka?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val futureResult = Future.sequence(
                  portfolio.getSecurities.toList map { security => (actorOf[SecurityProcessor].start() ? security).mapTo[Security] }
                ) map { securities => MergeHelper.merge(portfolio, securities) }
```

Comment: Really loved this suggestion and works as expected until i had to split it and add bunch of Eventhandler.info statements to debug an issue :(

Comment: def debug[T](t: T): T = { EventHandler.info(t); t }

Comment: I'm very glad you like it, please share your tears of joy and/or pain on the Akka mailinglist!